# Python Reddit Submission Text Slicing

Tags: python, string, slice, reddit, praw

I'm using Reddit's PRAW to collect submissions. I want to be able to slice the text of the submission and save it into a variable to compare against a hardcoded number to remove every submission post that has a number greater than it in its title.

```
import praw
reddit = praw.Reddit(client_id = 'REDACTED',
                    client_secret = 'REDACTED',
                    username = 'REDACTED', password = 'REDACTED',
                    user_agent = 'REDACTED')
subreddit = reddit.subreddit('NumbersReddit')
new_numpost = subreddit.new(limit=10)

for submission in new_numpost :
    if not submission.stickied:
        print(50*'-')
        print('User: {} '.format(submission.author))
        print('Title: {}'.format(submission.title))
        print('URL: {}'.format(submission.url))
```

Using the code above as a starting point: After removing the stickied submissions, I want to get the first two characters of the title of the post (which are and always will be 2 numbers, ie 24) and compare that against a hardcoded number, such as 18, so it then removes all posts that start with numbers greater than 18.

The following should be the output:

---

User: Example1

Title: 18 Years and I haven't realised this before

URL: https://www.reddit.com/r/NumbersReddit/comments/example1

---

User: Example2

Title: 18 times I tried this but it was worth it

URL: https://www.reddit.com/r/NumbersReddit/comments/example2

---

User: Example3

Title: 18 people said dieting was enough for them

URL: https://www.reddit.com/r/NumbersReddit/comments/example3

---

### Fix

Changed this:

```
for submission in new_numpost :
    if not submission.stickied:
        print(50*'-')
        print('User: {} '.format(submission.author))
        print('Title: {}'.format(submission.title))
        print('URL: {}'.format(submission.url))
```

To this:

```
for submission in new_numpost :
    if not submission.stickied:
        title_number = int(submission.title[:2])
        if title_number < 25:
            print(50*'-')
            print('User: {} '.format(submission.author))
            print('Title: {}'.format(submission.title))
            print('URL: {}'.format(submission.url))
```

Comment: So you're just trying to find the first two characters of the Title?

Comment: Yeah. I've looked up string slicing and can't make it work with what I have. If I can slice the string and get it saved then compare it, that would be good.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To get the first n number of characters of any string do the following:

(Assuming your title is "18: Hello!")

```
my_title = '18: Hello!'
print(my_title[:2])
```

Results in:

```
18
```

So for you you'd do the following on your title line:
`print('Title: {}'.format(submission.title[:2]))`

Assuming it's a string in there.

Once you have that, you can convert it to  an integer like so (assuming we haven't sliced it yet):

```
title = int(title[:2])
```

Then you can do whatever comparison you want with the int.

**Updated to further clarify answer:**

It seems your *full* title comes from `submission.title`, so what you can do is create two variables based on that:
One variable named `title_number` and another named `title` where `title_number = int(submission.title[:2])` and `title = submission.title` and all you do is compare the `title_number` and if it is greater than whatever number you get print the `title` in your for loop otherwise ignore it.

For example (assuming submission.title is '18 Years and I haven't realised this before')

```
check_int = 17
for submission in new_numpost:
    title = submission.title
    title_number = int(submission.title[:2])
    if title_number > check_int:
       print(title)
```

Should result in:

```
18 Years and I haven't realised this before
```

Being printed out

Comment: Adding onto what Treaty said, you can cast the data using str() if it is not currently a string

Comment: Just get the title from submission.title.

So `title = submission.title` then split that as you please.

Comment: I need to still keep the full title of the submission, but filter out all the ones that I don't want. I'll amend my post to show you what I mean with the title.

Comment: Oh, then just get the title number from a split name the variable `title_number = int(submission.title[:2])` and then you can name another variable `title = submission.title`

Now you have both the number of the title and the title itself.

Comment: Ah thats brilliant! I can see the logic there and it works, can't believe I didn't see it. Thanks a lot for your help.